# How to list all .mp3 file in phone storage and external storage ionic v2?

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins, angular2-services, angular2-directives, ngcordova

Help me to detect all mp3 files from both internal and external memory in ionic v2. I want create a mp3 player. But Can not listing mp3 file in Ionic v2